# htaccess url rewriting is failing

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am getting this error:

```
 Internal server error. Internal Server Error
 The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration
 and was unable to complete your request.
```

When I run  , I can see that mod_rewrite appears as a 'loaded module'.

Here is my htaccess rule, where I want to send any url which can't be resolved/found to index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
Rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Can someone please help me debug this? I am stuck...

Comment: you need to check apache error log to see what the real error is

Comment: enable the allow override to all in httpd.config or site enabled file

Comment: Where is your htaccess file and what happens when you try to access `index.php` directly?

Answer (score 1):

if you are in in WAMP localhost, then you need to configure "httpd.conf".

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I usually do ...

```
RewriteEngine On
# ignore rules if URL is file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# ignore rules if URL is directory
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# ignore rules if URL is not php
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.php$

# catch-all for routing
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Comment: OP is not passing the parameters to index.php so it doesn't make a difference of you have a match class or not.

Comment: Just tried. No it has the same problem as described in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Check your log files (find them in your vhosts file or the sites-available files) to get the error. Your .htaccess appears to be fine.